# Ruby on Rails: an efficient use of a class in lib/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been building a text parser. Ideally, it should be a static class:

```
keywords = Dictionary.parse(text)
```

However, the parser (lib/dictionary.rb) has to load some data (for instance, 'stop_words.txt') into memory as an array.

Therefore, as I understand, it can't be a static class, since I need a constructor, which would load that data before the parser can be used.

Then:

lib/dictionary.rb

```
def initialize
  @stop_words = load_stop_words
end
```

models/entry.rb

```
def parse
    @dictionary = Dictionary.new
    self.keywords = @dictionary.parse(self.text)
end
```

But how inefficient is that? Does it mean, that if I have 1000 entries, the Dictionary class loads 'stop_words.txt' 1000 times, even if the contents of the file are almost constant?

I guess, I am missing something here. There must be a better solution - either without creating multiple instances of the Dictionary class, or by loading data only once, when the application is running.

Comment: You could use the static approach by having a lazy initialization performed on first need in your Dictionary.parse method, leaving the stop_words list in a class (static) variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an initializer, which is stored in `config/initializers` and those are only loaded on startup, and perfect to load configuration files or setting up stuff. So your `Dictionary` is under '/lib`and in '/config/initializers` you create a file called `dictionary.rb` (or similar, the name is actually not important) 
which contains the code to load your keywords.

Answer (score 1):

So your pattern is that you would like a single instance of the object ( which is effectively constant and read-only after instantiation ) which is accessible from many callers but instantiates itself the first time it is called?

The name of this pattern is the *Singleton* and Ruby has it available as a mixin.

Comment: Static approach is also possible (see my comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Rails (as I assume by the tag and the lib directory) then it doesn't get loaded N times: lib files gets loaded only at Rails booting (if you change them, you need to restart the application) and so `stop_words` will be loaded just one time. Little example (`lib/timenow.rb`):

```
module Timenow
  @now = Time.now

  def self.doit
    Rails.logger.warn "TIME NOW IS: #{@now}"
  end
end
```

In any controller, `Timenow.doit` logs the time this module was loaded.